# How transfers rows to relationship edges in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have data as following in an excel sheet

```
A,B,C
D,E,F
```

I would like to transform it to

```
A,B
A,C
B,C
D,E
D,F
E,F
```

I have following Macro, Which only can make this :

```
A,B
A,C
D,E
D,F
```

How can I adjust the following code to serve the purpose?

```
Dim targetRowNumber As Long
targetRowNumber = Selection.Rows(Selection.Rows.Count).Row + 2

Dim col1 As Variant
Dim cell As Range

Dim sourceRow As Range: For Each sourceRow In Selection.Rows

    col1 = sourceRow.Cells(1).Value
    For Each cell In sourceRow.Cells

        If Not cell.Column = Selection.Column Then
            Selection.Worksheet.Cells(targetRowNumber, 1) = col1
            Selection.Worksheet.Cells(targetRowNumber, 2) = cell.Value
            targetRowNumber = targetRowNumber + 1
        End If

    Next cell

Next sourceRow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a second loop in your macro to achieve the results I as understood them:

```
Dim targetRowNumber As Long
targetRowNumber = Selection.Rows(Selection.Rows.Count).Row + 2

Dim col1 As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim colCounter As Long
Dim colCounter2 As Long

Dim sourceRow As Range: For Each sourceRow In Selection.Rows

    For colCounter = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count - 1

        'col1 = sourceRow.Cells(colCounter).Value
        'For Each cell In sourceRow.Cells
        col1 = sourceRow.Cells(colCounter).Value
        For colCounter2 = colCounter + 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
            Set cell = sourceRow.Cells(, colCounter2)

            If Not cell.Column = Selection.Column Then
                Selection.Worksheet.Cells(targetRowNumber, 1) = col1
                Selection.Worksheet.Cells(targetRowNumber, 2) = cell.Value
                targetRowNumber = targetRowNumber + 1
            End If

        Next colCounter2

    Next colCounter

Next sourceRow
```

Note that performance would be greatly improved if you copy the selection into a local variable (array) to work off of, create the results in an array, and then copy the contents back to the sheet when you are done. That might not really matter unless you are working on much larger sets of data though.

Comment: I am sorry, but my rows are not all equal

A,B,C,D,F

G,H,

this code create a blank relation too, Can you please adjust it too continue it only before it reach to blank cell in row.

I have actually very large data set, I have no idea how to implement your comment regarding using arrays if you can help me will be very useful.

Thank you so much,
Ali

Comment: can you post a sample of what you mean by rows are not equal and the results you would desire in that case?